# How can I locate python2 path within python3 code?

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, python-2.7

I use both python 2 and python 3 on my machine.  I take advantage of the she-bang notation at the top of my python scripts and use the new python launcher that came with python 3.

I would like to locate the python 2 path for python.exe from within a python 3 script running on windows.

sys.executable and similar commands won't work because it shows the path to the currently running python.  It will not show the path to another version of python.

Comment: I was just about to give you a checkmark for your answer, but your answer was deleted?

Comment: @panofish: It was deleted because it's not a good idea to assume Python 2 will appear in the `PATH` at all (the `py.exe` launcher removes the need for that, and properly manages *all* the Python versions on the system without relying on the `PATH`).

Comment: I guess you meant to ping @Jean-FrançoisFabre

Comment: @panofish are you sure you can use this answer and not cody's ? if so I'll undelete. if you have `py` properly configured, it's much better to use it

Comment: Cody's answer is better, but I liked the insight that your code provided.  That's ok, I have a copy of your answer.  Thanks @Jean-FrançoisFabre

Comment: no problem. I think it answers some question, but probably not that one

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about the following? It utilizes the new launcher to execute python2, and gives it a one-liner to print `sys.executable`, so it's the python2 interpreter running it.

```
import subprocess

print(str(subprocess.run(['py', '-2', '-c', 'import sys;print(sys.executable)'],
               stdout=subprocess.PIPE).stdout, 'utf-8'))
```

Output:

```
$ python -V
Python 3.6.5

$ python get_two.py
C:\Python27\python.exe
```

Comment: `subprocess.run` in 3.6+ has `encoding` and `errors`. Note that in general the encoding for standard output that's piped from Windows Python should be `'mbcs'`, unless `PYTHONIOENCODING` is set, but in this case it doesn't matter since the output is ASCII.

Comment: Perfect!  Thanks cody